# use passed in parameter as property in filter, angular

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, include, subscribe

I have a search filter that seaches on different parameters like title, description, price.
My filter works well but I want the parameter to change based on the passed in parameter of `filterBy`

Like this works:

```
 filterItems(filterBy: string, filterText: string): Subscription {
    return this.http
      .get<{ items: Items[] }>(this.API)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((items) => {
        this.itemsArray = items.items;
        this.itemsArray = this.itemsArray.filter((item) => {
          return item.title.includes(`${filterText}`);
        });
      });
  }
```

But this DOESN'T WORK:

```
filterItems(filterBy: string, filterText: string): Subscription {
    return this.http
      .get<{ items: Items[] }>(this.API)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((items) => {
        this.itemsArray = items.items;
        this.itemsArray = this.itemsArray.filter((item) => {
          return item[filterBy].includes(`${filterText}`);
        });
      });
  }
```

The `filterBy` is correctly passing down 'title' as a string, so how can I make this property of `item` dynamic?

Error message:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Items'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Items'.
```

Items interface:

```
export interface Items {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  price: string;
  email: string;
  image: string;
}
```

Comment: why doesnt this work? what do you get?

Comment: If you do a console.log(filterBy === “title”) you get true?

Comment: @Moshezauros I get this: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Items'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Items'. I will show more code above in the question to clarify things

Comment: @bjlasc01 yes sir indeed, it logs true

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an indexer to the interface, this was a new concept for me. So this worked:

```
export type Items = {
  [filterBy: string]: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  price: string;
  email: string;
  image: string;
};
```